# WCF service works on local machine but does not work from remote machine

Tags: wcf

I have a simple WCF service. It is hosted in IIS. Remote clients are able to pickup the metadata, and generate proxy code. But when a service call is made, there is no response from the service. My WCF service code is never hit. The problem happens even before that. Here is the stack trace. How can I fix this? The service works locally (i.e., on same machine which is hosting the service). I am not doing any authentication etc.

```
The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The
 time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableRequestor.ThrowTimeoutException()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableRequestor.Request(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableSession.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(Tim
eSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceMod
el.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeo
ut)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeS
pan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean on
eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim
eout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCall
Message methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Adding config file in response to comment:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>        
        <add relativeAddress="Service1.svc" service="WcfService1.Service1"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>      
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://mymachine.mydomain.com/Service1/" />            
          </baseAddresses>                    
        </host>
        <endpoint address="Service1"
                  binding ="customBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="NetHttpBinding"
                  contract="WcfService1.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <!-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323713(v=vs.100).aspx
           You must add the binding elements in the following order: Transaction Flow, Reliable Session, Security,
           Composite Duplex, One-way, Stream Security, Message Encoding, and Transport.-->
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="NetHttpBinding">
          <reliableSession />          
          <compositeDuplex />
          <oneWay />
          <binaryMessageEncoding />          
          <httpTransport maxBufferSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

clients can access static html file, and also the metadata page, wsdl, can create proxy also.

EDIT: if I change binding to basicHttpBinding, it works. But I need to make it work with this custom binding.

EDIT: the culprits seem to be the `<compositeDuplex/>` and `<oneWay/>` elements. If I remove them from the binding, it works (for now that is; why it does not work with the elements - I don't know). For completeness, if I only remove either `<oneWay/>` or `<compositeDuplex/>` (**but not both**) I get this error when trying to access metadata:

```
Binding 'CustomBinding' doesn't support creating any channel types. This often indicates that the BindingElements in a CustomBinding have been stacked incorrectly or in the wrong order. A Transport is required at the bottom of the stack. The recommended order for BindingElements is: TransactionFlow, ReliableSession, Security, CompositeDuplex, OneWay, StreamSecurity, MessageEncoding, Transport.
```

If both are left in the binding then service works locally but remote clients never get back a response when a method is invoked.

Comment: Please include the WCF config. Also try and put a static html file on the IIS server and see if that gets hit. If not, it might be a firewall issue.

Comment: do you need a clientBaseAddress for compositeDuplex  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731351(v=vs.85).aspx